# Problem deploying Angular + Node with Heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku

I struggle deploying my node.js(TS)/angular app with heroku.

When I try to deploy it on git with `git push heroku master`, every step go fine until the `heroku-postbuild` one.

Hence, it returns the following :

```
Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
remote: An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/tmp/build_24879b07/front/node_modules'
remote: See "/tmp/ng-REYivA/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

My project architecture is...

```
Project
|
|-- api/...
|-- front/...
|-- package.json
|-- ...
```

...which might cause some problems.

In addition, here are the most probably concerned files :

./package.json

```
{
  "name": "mymusicads",
  "scripts": {
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd front && ng build --configuration production",
    "start": "cd api && npm run start"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x",
    "npm": "7.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/core": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.2.13",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  }
}
```

./api/index.ts

```
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import path from 'path';
import { adDataRoutes } from './app/routes/ad-data.route';
import { errorHandler } from './middleware/error.middleware';
import { notFoundHandler } from './middleware/not-found.middleware';

dotenv.config();

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api/addata', adDataRoutes);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'mymusicads', 'dist', 'front')));

app.use(errorHandler);
app.use(notFoundHandler);

app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'mymusicads', 'dist', 'front', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${process.env.PORT || 3000}`);
});
```

./front/angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "front": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/front",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "3mb",
                  "maximumError": "6mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "10kb",
                  "maximumError": "20kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "front:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "front:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "front:build"
          }
        },
        "test": { [...] },
        "lint": { [...] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "front"
}
```

From what I understood, the problem come from my `api/index.ts` file, I may not be targeting the right path with `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'mymusicads', 'dist', 'front', 'index.html'))`.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't recall if I ran into the same issue exactly, but had a different setup. In `front` folder I had a package.json specifically for Angular app - basically the default Angular CLI setup

Top level `package.json` had very few dependencies (if any), mainly scripts (client folder where you use front). For prebuild, run `npm install` in client folder, and  `npm run --prefix client build -- -- prod`

For the server:

```js
// Static files
app.use(
    express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist/my-app'), {
        maxAge: '1y',
    })
);
// Angular app
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(
        path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist/my-app/index.html')
    );
});
```

Comment: Hello Drenai,
That's interesting ! I think you put the finger on something important here, my static folder may not exist.
I changed the path for it to match my app (eg `__dirname/../../front/dist/front`), but I actually realize the problem may be somewhere else.
The error being
`ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/tmp/build_24879b07/front/node_modules'
`, it seems that heroku doesn't find the node_modules folder in my front app... Do I forgot something about that ?

Comment: I think it was that ! I added `npm install &&` before my build instruction in front package.json, it seems to have unlocked the situation. I'll keep investigating this ASAP, another error rose about bad version of `@angular/compiler-cli`.

Comment: Ah cool, nice one

Comment: Indeed, I forgot the prebuild phase ! But double checking the static destination as firstly mentioned surely avoided me some errors after prebuild. Thanks !